# How to start animation while returning to parent activity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-animation

I am starting an Activity when an icon is clicked in the ActionBar and I am making an animation for a transition. 
Here is the code :

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_menu) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(NewsFeedActivity.this, RightHalfMenu.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left);
    }
```

Now I also want to animate when I click the on Back Arrow button to return to the parent activity.
In default transition parent activity fades in, I want to animate appearance of Parent activity from Right to Left.

Here is the code :

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if(id == R.id.home){
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        //for putting animation
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_right);

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

In default transition parent activity fades in, I want to animate appearance of Parent activity from Right to Left.
How I can do this?

P.S: I have removed this code

```
  if(id == R.id.home){
    NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
    //for putting animation
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right,R.anim.slide_out_right);

}
```

and even then on back click it is going to NewsFeedActivity because I have declared  NewsFeedActivity as parent activity of RighHalf in AndroidMinifest.xml.

```
<activity
    android:name=".activities.RightHalfMenu"
    android:parentActivityName=".activities.NewsFeedActivity">

    <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".activities.NewsFeedActivity"/>
    >
</activity>
```

Comment: what exactly is your problem?

Comment: Default transition is activity fades in, I want to animate appearance of Parent activity from Right to Left.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work with the

```
    NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
```

method. You'd have to start your ParentActivity via an Intent like you did in your first snippet :

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(RightHalfMenu.this, NewsFeedActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_right);
```

or use the [NavUtils.navigateUpTo()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NavUtils.html#navigateUpTo(android.app.Activity,%20android.content.Intent)) method with an Intent f.e. :

```
    NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, new Intent(RightHalfMenu.this, NewsFeedActivity.class));
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_right);
```

Comment: dear actually problem is not with loading activity, it successfully loads parent activity, but default appearance of parent activity is, it fades it. But I want to animate appearance of parent activity from right to left

Comment: It is not working. Actually I removed this code `if(id == R.id.home){
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        //for putting animation
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_right);

    }` and even then on back click it is going to NewsFeedActivity because I have declared  NewsFeedActivity as parent activity of RighHalf in AndroidMinifest.xml. `if(id == R.id.home){
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        //for putting animation
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_right);

    }`